# Combine similar elements in a Java Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

How to combine consecutive similar objects that are in a Java Stream?

Till now I could not find a good solution, so I hope you can help.

Suppose we have a class like the following:

```
class Someclass {
     String type;
     int count;
}
```

When having a Stream { "a", 1 }, { "a", 2}, { "b", 4}, { "b", "5" } and that needs to be processed as { "a", 3 }, { "b", 9 }.

Combining means of course, adding the counts for the objects with the same type.

How to do?

Comment: You could use [groupingBy](https://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector), but instead of using a Stream, you might be better off putting the data into a Map, keyed on String type, and using [Map.merge](https://www.baeldung.com/java-merge-maps).

Comment: Thank you. Maps are not useful, because I have to process them sequentially. Most of the time they are unary.

Comment: `.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(YourClass::getType, Collectors.summingInt(YourClass::getCount)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) to collect the stream into the desired `Map`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class MyType {
    String type;
    int count;

    public MyType(String type, int count) {
        this.type = type;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<MyType> list = List.of(new MyType("a", 1), 
                                    new MyType("a", 2), 
                                    new MyType("b", 4), 
                                    new MyType("b", 5));

        Map<String, Integer> map = list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(MyType::getType, MyType::getCount, Integer::sum));

        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{a=3, b=9}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assume you had a list of maps as in your example.

- first stream the list
- then flatten all the `entrySets` into a single stream.
- the collect each `key/value` pair
- use the `(a,b)->a+b` merge function to add values for duplicate keys.

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> maps = List.of(Map.of("a", 1),
        Map.of("a", 2), Map.of("b", 4), Map.of("b", 5));
Map<String, Integer> result =
        maps.stream().flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
                        Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> a + b));
System.out.println(result);
```

Prints

```
{a=3, b=9}
```

If you had an array of objects, you could do it as follows.
The `compute` method puts the value there if it isn't present, or adds to the existing one if it is present.

```
Object[] values = {"a",1,"b",4,"a",2,"b",5};
Map<String,Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < values.length-1; i+=2) {
    Integer val = (Integer)values[i+1];
    map1.compute((String)values[i], (k,v)->v == null ? val : v +val); 
}

System.out.println(map1);
```